# Write .pypirc file programmatically

Tags: python, config, pypi

Is there some library available to write a `~/.pypirc` file programmatically?

Also, what is the formal spec of its format?  All I've found is this section of the docs:

https://docs.python.org/3.3/distutils/packageindex.html#pypirc

That leaves out details like what kinds of whitespace are allowable, whether `=` and `:` are equivalent or not, and so on.

Comment: It's a regular `ini`-style configuration file, almost certainly parsed using the `configparser` module by tools written in Python.

Comment: @chepner reference on the internet for that fact?  Otherwise you could write that as an answer and this SO page can be that reference.

Comment: @chepner also, https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#customizing-parser-behaviour says "There are nearly as many INI format variants as there are applications using it. `configparser` goes a long way to provide support for the largest sensible set of INI styles available." So even supposing that `configparser` is being used, it doesn't really tell me what the format allows, or how to write an acceptable one to whatever's going to parse it.

Comment: If it's `configparser`, then you can use whatever the `configparser` module says you can use. But to know if `configparser` *is* used, you first need to know which tool will actually be *reading* the file.

Comment: @chepner No, I need to use whatever options `distutils` is expecting, which AFAICT aren't documented except by example.

Comment: OK, what options are accepted is an entirely different question than the syntactic format of the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

The file is read by [`distutils/config.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/distutils/config.py) using `RawConfigParser`.

So if you want to write it use the same `RawConfigParser`. The docs you pointed are the only docs. The rest could be deduced from the code.